# Killing a child process from within itself in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, kill-process, child-process

Is there a way to kill make a child process "suicide"? I tried with `process.exit(1)` but apparently it kills the whole application I'm running. I just want to kill the child process (like when we call `process.kill()` from the "father" of the child process). Also  calling `process.kill()` within the child process kills the whole application.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`process` is always a reference to the main process. But you can simply use this:

```
var spawn = require( "child_process" ).spawn;

// example child process
var grep = spawn( "grep", [ "ssh"] );

grep.on( "exit", function (code, signal) {
    console.log( "child process terminated due to receipt of signal "+signal);
});

grep.kill( "SIGHUP" );
```

I guess it depends on how you use child processes. But if you don't have a reference to the child process, then there is not much you can do.

**WARNING:** Killing child processes is almost never a good idea. You should send a message to the child processes and handle it in that process.

Comment: I don't see how grepping "ssh" from the list of my processes can help me kill the process itself, but thanks for the insight. I don't have the process reference within itself but I can easily manage to get it.

Comment: @Masiar That's just an example of child process, grep has nothing to do with the problem. :D Yeah, get the reference and you'll be ok.

Comment: and by the way I'm handling the graceful exit of the process :) that's why I want to kill it within itself: I want to handle some last stuff.

Comment: Maybe you could provide an example on how to send a signal to the child process so that it exits gracefully.  I'm not finding good examples of that.